# Cannot push to array state in Redux Tookit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux Toolkit but I can't seem to find a way to add a new value of an array of objects.

Here's my reducer:

```js
import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {
  positions: []
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setPositionsAction(state, { payload }) {
      state.positions = payload
    },
    addPositionAction(state, { payload }) {
      state.positions.push(payload)
    }
  }
})

export const {
  setPositionsAction,
  addPositionAction
} = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

I'm dispatching the request after a successful axios request

```
dispatch(addPositionAction(response))
```

But the state gets deleted and only contains the new value I just added, removing completely all the data that was containing before.

What am I missing?

Comment: Haven’t used redux for while. My guess state.positions.push(payload) should be written as state.positions = [ ....state.positions, payload]

Comment: Please post the full code, the slice should work properly, are you sure you're not calling `setPositionsAction` somewhere? `setPositionsAction` definitely will replace everything in the store with the payload.

Comment: @DraganS what OP wrote works with redux toolkit just fine, it uses immer underneath so you don't need to care about immutability

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `dispatch(addPositionAction(response))`?